# Items disappear after ~10 seconds [Angular2, *ngFor]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular2 template that looks like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let message of messages">
  {{ message.content }}
</span>
```

And the corresponding TS logic behind it:

```
let a = new Map();
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  a.set(i, { content: i.toString() });
}

this.messages = a.values();
```

I can see a list of 100 items in my view, but after a few seconds (from 5 to 15 seconds), they disappear without any error/warning.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Plunker or any other working, minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: @Kinduser I created a plunkr, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm not sure if the bug happens immediately or if I'm doing something wrong: https://plnkr.co/edit/US3uPVe4jVfElGNkOXCx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't receive any visible changes because before the `for` loop finishes iteration over the `map` variable, you are assigning empty (at that moment) `map` element to the `messages` variable.

Possible solution would be adding a `setTimeout` function to wait the loop to finish.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.messages = a.values();
}, 200);
```

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/TbNlr8mf9mqylbm4Q4iw?p=preview)**

**Note**: Fellow programmers, we have a little issue here, how is it possible that `a.values()` function doesn't wait for the loop to end? It behave like an asynchro call... I was able to fix it with `setTimeout`, but it isn't effective in a longer term.

Anyone have any idea why does it work this way?

Comment: Ok, this solves the plunkr issue, but it doesn't trigger my initial problem. Why could be the data disappearing? How could I debug the root cause of it?

Comment: @alexandernst To be honest, that issue in plunker worths a separate question, because how it is possible that the `.values()` function is being called before the `for` loop ends? This is weird and this question needs someone more clever than me. And about your issue - this is hard to judge why does it disappears, that `values()` function seems suspicious for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking the same. Maybe `values()` is creating some temporal iterator that Chrome's GC deletes after a few seconds because it can't properly detect that Angular is still using it?

Comment: @alexandernst I've came up with something. Would you change your lifecycle hook `OnInit` to `AfterViewInit`?